# Can Quicksilver be configured to open folders in new Finder tabs?

Tags: finder, quicksilver

Is there a way to configure Quicksilver so it will open folders in new Finder tabs? Right now, when I use QS to navigate to a folder location and select the "Open" option from the actions pane QS opens a new Finder window at that folder location.

Now that there are tabs in the Finder, I'd like it to bring an existing Finder window to the front and open the selected file in a new tab. Is that even possible, since tabs are a new feature of Mavericks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the record: A *Quicksilver Action* Apple script for *Open in New Tab* was posted on the Quicksilver blog: [Opening Folders in Finder Tabs](http://blog.qsapp.com/post/66560143350/opening-folders-in-finder-tabs).

Answer (score 1):

For folders, as with any other type of file, Quicksilver just asks OS X to open the file. The OS decides what to do from there.

It’s the same as typing `open /path/to/folder` in Terminal. So, if you can get *that* to open folders in a new tab, Quicksilver should start doing it too.

(I think Finder would need a preference to control this behavior, and I don’t see one.)